# Invoking a child function from another function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I am trying to add an inner function to the function and invoking that child function from another function.

My function driver code is as below which i cannot modify:

```
const obj =  function1();
obj.method1(soemobject);
```

The definition for the function1() which is already present is as below:

```
function function1(){

}
```

What I want to achieve is adding a method inside function1 so that i can call it from another function:

```
function function1(){
    function method1(item){
       console.log(item)
}
}
```

The error I am getting is:

[image]

with the code chunk

```
function function1(){
        function method1(item){
           console.log(item)
    }
    this.method1 = method1
    }
```

and

[image]

with the code chunk

```
 function function1(){
        function method1(item){
           console.log(item)
    }
    }
```

What I have tried so far is:

1. Making it a constructive function: But as the driver code cannot be modified, this won't work as it needs to be called with a new keyword.
2. Tried accessing function1's properties using this keyword, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Define function1 like this:

```
 function function1(){
      return {
       method1: function(item){
           console.log(item)
       }
      } 
    }
```

The result from calling function1 is stored as obj

```
const obj =  function1();
```

method1 is called on obj

```
obj.method1(soemobject);
```

obj in this case is:

```
{
    method1: function(item){
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: These worked, Thank you. The question is I want to return an array instead of console log it? and along with method1, I also have a few more methods to invoke from the same function, will the syntax be the same? separated by ","?

Comment: You can return an array or anything from within method1.
```method1: function(item){
   return  [item]
}```

Yes, adding another function in the returned object obj along with method1 is just the same syntax separated by, : ```return {
       method1: function(item){
           console.log(item)
       }, method2:function(){}
      }```

If it worked, please accept the Answer:)